# Array being chopped off over ajax post. Ajax posting limit?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array, which consists of 426 smaller arrays, which also comprise of 4 attributes.. Below is an example of one of 426 arrays...

```
    array( //Main array
          0 => array( //1 of 426 arrays
               'name' => 'Danny', 
               'email' => 'your@email.com', 
               'picture_url' => 'http://www.website.com', 
                'score' => 89
          ),
    )
```

I'm posting this array with jquery's ajax functions to a php file, which adds them to a database... My problem is that the array seems to be chopped off when it's posted to the php file. Only about half the array actually reaches the php file...

This has led me to believe that there may be a file size limit when posting over ajax. However, the size of my array seems to be relatively small..

I'm running my application on WAMP..

Can anyone shed some light what's possibly happening?

UPDATE:

I'm posting my array like so:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "invite_friends.php",
  data: {
    theID: me.id,
    friends: multidimensional_array //This is the array <---
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    return console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    return alert("Error: Oops, there has been a problem");
  }
});
```

And I retrieve my array (in invite_friends.php) like so..

```
if($_POST['friends']) {
    $friends = $_POST['friends'];   
} else {
    $friends = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: How do you post your array? Can you share the code?

Comment: When you say post do you mean get ?

Comment: According to w3schools.com (yes, I know: http://w3fools.com) GET has size limitations, but POST doesn't.

Comment: @Mathieu - Certainly, I've updated my question above :)

Comment: I've got the same problem. Have you come across any solutions, Danny?

Comment: See my answer below - I just figured this out!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to open your `php.ini` file and set (or create) this line:

`max_input_vars = 1000000`

`max_input_vars` has a default value of 1000, which will cut off an array at 1000 total elements. Just change it to a really high number (in my case, I needed to set it to one million).

From the PHP Manual:

> How many input variables may be accepted (limit is applied to $_GET,
>   $_POST and $_COOKIE superglobal separately). Use of this directive
>   mitigates the possibility of denial of service attacks which use hash
>   collisions. If there are more input variables than specified by this
>   directive, an E_WARNING is issued, and further input variables are
>   truncated from the request. ***This limit applies only to each nesting
>   level of a multi-dimensional input array.***

**Keep in mind:** As the manual says, this default limit was put in place to prevent denial of service attacks.

Hope this helps even though this is an old question.

Comment: Is then better solution to send each array, one by one via Ajax, in some loop than send it at once, if php.ini is unreachable?

Comment: The accepted answer is either incorrect or it masks the actual problem.  The correct way to pass an array to PHP via AJAX is to first JSON.stringify the array and then json_decode it on the PHP side.  I had a multidimensional array, 595 x 4, and this was the only solution that worked of the several proposed.  It had nothing to do with server limits of any kind.

Answer (score 8):

You should convert all your data in json format at the client side and send it as a text.

```
var jsonDataString = JSON.stringify(data)
//data - array, associative array, any other variables

$.ajax({
...
    data: {
        friends: jsonDataString,
    }
...
});
```

At the server side just decode json file.

```
<?php
...
$friendsJsonString = $_POST['friends'];
$friends = json_decode($friendsJsonString);
...
```

Changing of php.ini is not a good idea because of security risks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem.

```
$.ajax({data:{x:x,y:y}});
```

Finally it turns out that some of the values are date format (object).  When they are converted to simple types (string or integer), the problem is solved. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your php_value post_max_size to at least 16M in your .htaccess and max_input_time so that you do not get a time out.

```
php_value post_max_size 16M
php_value max_input_time 4000
```

Comment: I've added these to my htaccess and changed my php ini file, and I'm afraid this hasn't helped.

Comment: can you try getting the whole array post and saving it into a file using your console just to check how large is the array you are posting

Comment: Sorry for the late response, was out of the office until the morning. I have placed all the contents of the array in a text file, and the size is 48 KB

Comment: @Danny that means there is something else that's wrong because such a small post would not time out. Are you sure you dont have any sort of validation in your code that would affect the POST data? PS turn off magic quotes as well.

Comment: Ok magic quotes have been disabled.. There is no more validation than shown in my code above I'm afraid. I have taken a screenshot of my array in the console. http://postimage.org/image/9bwfov2nj/ - I've noticed it's a multi-dimensional array with objects. Perhaps this makes a difference?

Comment: Maybe that is the case, try to not store the __proto__ object in your array, but otherwise there shouldn't be any issues because I work with even bigger multidimensional arrays