# Data is getting lost during $.post

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache, maxlength

I have a list `<ul>` of articles `<li>` and an event handler on a button.

When clicking the button, I aggregate all `<li>`s ID (integer) using:

```
data.articles  = $('#category-articles').sortable('toArray');

// alerts 1298
alert(data.articles.length);

$.post(....);
```

On the serverside:

```
<?php
// echoes 968
echo sizeof($_POST['articles']);
```

**Making it clear:**

- trying to send **1298** items in an array `data.articles`
- receiving only the first **968** items in an array `$_POST['articles']`

Data is getting lost during post action. There is no code between the actual post and the target PHP that could filter or remove any items.

I'm using apache and PHP 5.3.

Request:

```
Content-Length: up to 80,000 bytes
```

Server:

```
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

I enabled error reporting but it just shrinks my array and I don't get why it doesn't sent the full data. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Do you receive first 968 items or is the order random?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek **first** ordered 968 items not shuffled.

Comment: What is the nesting level of your `POST` data?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I am not the system administrator and not allowed to change configuration or even reload the server config. I think 80K should fit into 100M :/

Comment: @hindmost Nothing is actually nested, there are a view fields like title, ... then articles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate of [Array being chopped off over ajax post. Ajax posting limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462840/array-being-chopped-off-over-ajax-post-ajax-posting-limit) ?

Suggests that it's to do with PHP's  max_input_vars:
**This limit applies only to each nesting level of a multi-dimensional input array.**

To solve this without editing the server configuration:

```
// Serialize the elements into a single var using join():

data.articles  = $('#category-articles').sortable('toArray').join(';');
```

And on the serverside:

```
// Unserializing the single variable back into an array:

$articles = explode(';', $_POST['articles']);
```

The delimiting char `;` **must not** appear inside the elements, chose a different character if it is a problem.

Comment: The value is `1000` !

Comment: This should be a comment, not answer

Comment: Apologies @hindmost - I don't have 50 rep. I thought this might be useful, so wanted to contribute somehow!

Comment: @DanFromGermany As you wrote above, there are some fields beside `articles`. So most likely they consume the rest of limit (1000 - 968 = 32)

Comment: @DaveSalomon may I edit my solution into your question?

Comment: @Dave Salomon You have 50 rep and even more

Comment: This saved my day and with my edit it's a full legit answer :-)