# Updates Stopping at 768 Records

Tags: php, mysql

This scripts I am running is to update a table, the problem that I am having is that in the process of running the updates, it just stops updating the table at the 768th row.

Why could this be happening?

Scripts 1 is called `doAllocate.php` and is as below:

```
<?php
$status=trim($_GET['status']);
$region=$_GET['regg'];
include_once ('connstring.php');

$dir=1;
$query ;
$flag="unattended";
$cids=array();
$acc=array();
$c=0;
$a=0;
$var="";
$q="";
$p;     

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
or die("<script> alert('Unable to connect to MySQL'); </script>");

$selected = mysql_select_db("edgars",$dbhandle)
or die("<script> alert('Could not select database'); </script>");

$query1="SELECT * 
           FROM collectors 
          WHERE status='$status' AND 
                region='$region' ";
//$query1="SELECT * FROM collectors where status='1' and region='1' ";
$res1=mysql_query($query1);
$i=0;
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($res1))
{
    $cids[$i]=$r['cid'];
    $i++;
}

$query="SELECT * 
          FROM customers  
         WHERE status='$status' AND 
               flag='$flag' AND 
               region='$region' AND 
               cid='' 
      ORDER BY total_due DESC";
//$query="SELECT * FROM customers  where status='1' and flag='$flag' and region='1' ORDER BY total_due DESC";

$res=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_num_rows($res);
$j=0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $acc[$j]=$row['account'];
    $j++;
}

for($c=0,$a=0 ; $c<count($cids),$a<count($acc);$c++,$a++)   
{
    $q= mysql_query("UPDATE customers 
                        SET cid='$cids[$c]' 
                      WHERE account='$acc[$a]' AND 
                            cid=''");
    $rcount = mysql_affected_rows();
    if($rcount > 0)
    {
        header("Location: doAllocateRev.php?status=".$status."&regg=".$region);
    }
}
?>
```

Scripts 2 is called `doAllocateRev.php` and is as below:

```
<?php
$status=trim($_GET['status']);
$region=$_GET['regg'];
include_once ('connstring.php');

$dir=1;
$query ;
$flag="unattended";
$cids=array();
$acc=array();
$c=0;
$a=0;
$var="";
$q="";
$p;     

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
or die("<script> alert('Unable to connect to MySQL'); </script>");

$selected = mysql_select_db("edgars",$dbhandle)
or die("<script> alert('Could not select database'); </script>");

$query1="SELECT * 
           FROM collectors 
          WHERE status='$status' AND 
                region='$region' ";
//$query1="SELECT * FROM collectors  where status='1' and region='1' ";
$res1=mysql_query($query1);
$i=0;
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($res1))
{
    $cids[$i]=$r['cid'];
    $i++;
}

$query="SELECT * 
          FROM customers  
         WHERE status='$status' AND 
               flag='$flag' AND 
               region='$region' AND 
               cid='' 
      ORDER BY total_due DESC";
//$query="SELECT * FROM customers  where status='1' and flag='$flag' and region='1' ORDER BY total_due DESC";

$res=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_num_rows($res);
$j=0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $acc[$j]=$row['account'];
    $j++;
}

for( $c=count($cids)-1; $c>=0,$a<count($acc) ; $c--,$a++)   
{
    $p= mysql_query("UPDATE customers 
                        SET cid='$cids[$c]'
                      WHERE account='$acc[$a]' AND
                            cid=''");
    $rcount = mysql_affected_rows();
    if($rcount > 0) 
    {
        header("Location: doAllocate.php?status=".$status."&regg=".$region);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: maybe because of limitation of database storage. check my.ini file ..

Comment: Your `for` will never run fully with that `header` inside of it, every single successful update will trigger the affected rows to 1, hence it will try to redirect you before you end the entire code.

Comment: 1) `mysql` is deprecated, stop using it! `mysqli` or `PDO` are what you should be using.
2) You using values pulled from a `SELECT` to do get PHP to do a `UPDATE`, instead it might be better to rewrite the query to `UPDATE` directly-- to prevent PHP timeouts
3) your code is probably timing out, preventing the update from finishing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what you're trying to put into the database, but I do know that mysql can produce errors when you try to write a key of length more than 767 to an innoDb table. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html ("By default, an index key for a single-column index can be up to 767 bytes"). The fact that you are hitting a limit at 768 makes me suspect that this is related. If it's a coincidence, it's an interesting one.

Answer (score 0):

Two points here which maybe help.

```
$p= mysql_query("UPDATE customers 
                    SET cid='$cids[$c]'
                  WHERE account='$acc[$a]' AND
                        cid=''");
```

Avoid this. Properly concatenate variables:

```
$p= mysql_query("UPDATE customers 
                    SET cid='" . $cids[$c] . "'
                  WHERE account='" . $acc[$a] . "' AND
                        cid=''");
```

I recently had a similiar problem: [Data is getting lost during $.post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677445/data-is-getting-lost-during-post)

It may be due to `max_input_vars` variable.

Share your output of `ini_get('max_input_vars');` and consider raising it.