# AJAX request from Codeigniter view gives an error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, csrf

**CSRF protection is enabled.**

I have a view
[image]

I am trying to insert the shifts to the database table via AJAX.

```
$('#insert_shift').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var empty_td = $('.td_shift[data-type=""]').size();
    if (empty_td == 0) {
        var date = $('#atdnc_date').val() + '-';
        var arr = [];
        var new_arr = [];
        $('.td_shift').each(function() {

            //if($(this).attr('data-day') != 0){

            var data_type = $(this).attr('data-type');
            var shift_atdnc_id = $(this).attr('data-typeid');
            var user_id = $(this).attr('data-user');
            var new_date = date + $(this).attr('data-day');

            if (data_type == 'shift') {
                var shift_strt_time = $(this).attr('data-start');
                var shift_end_time = $(this).attr('data-end'); // Change new_arr to old
                var new_arr = {
                    'shift': shift_atdnc_id,
                    'user_id': user_id,
                    'date': new_date,
                    'shift_strt_time': shift_strt_time,
                    'shift_end_time': shift_end_time,
                    'checkin_time': '00:00:00',
                    'checkout_time': '00:00:00',
                    'time_spent': '00:00:00',
                    'checkin_reason': 'NA',
                    'checkout_reason': 'NA',
                    'work_report': 'NA',
                    'attn_status': 0
                };
            } else if (data_type == 'attendance') {
                var new_arr = {
                    'shift': shift_atdnc_id,
                    'user_id': user_id,
                    'date': new_date,
                    'shift_strt_time': '00:00:00',
                    'shift_end_time': '00:00:00',
                    'checkin_time': '00:00:00',
                    'checkout_time': '00:00:00',
                    'time_spent': '00:00:00',
                    'checkin_reason': 'NA',
                    'checkout_reason': 'NA',
                    'work_report': 'NA',
                    'attn_status': shift_atdnc_id
                };
            }

            arr.push(new_arr);

            //}

        });
        $.post(base_url + 'test_shift/insert_shift', {
                a: arr,
                csrf_test_name: csrf_token
            },
            function(data) {
                alert(data);
                if (data == 1) {
                    document.location.href = base_url + 'test_shift';
                } else {
                    alert("error");
                }
            }
        );
    } else {
        alert("Please fill all the shifts");
    }
});
```

If there are only 2 rows of shift, the values are getting inserted. But if there are more, 3 in this case, nothing is getting inserted to db but getting an error in the console.

> An Error Was Encountered      The action you have requested is not
>   allowed.

When I did a search on this error I came to know that this is thrown in the case of CSRF issues. But I couldn't find a way to fix the issue. Could someone please help?

**UPDATE**

When I changed the order of data in the POST the above error has disappeared. But now another one came up.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice Message:  Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php Line Number: 589

And a database error. The INSERT query goes like this

```
INSERT into table_name () values ('1','some_value'),('2','some_value2'),Array
```

The code used to generate the array of items is same but from arr[83] the problem starts. I have tried deleting the tds after 83rd day(which is day 23 in 3rd row) from browser and the code worked. I don't understand what is happening here. The 83rd array got chopped for some reason by PHP(or CI).

Comment: add this in controller or in `config.php`,  `$config['csrf_protection'] = false;`

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju: I can't do that.

Comment: does this error comes everytime??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju: If there are only 2 rows of shift, the values are getting inserted. But if there are more, 3 in this case, nothing is getting inserted to db but getting an error in the console.

Comment: i think you are passing more values, but im not sure, try `json_encode()` ans send, in controller `json_decode()`.

Comment: How are you generating your UI – is this just one form, or a unique form for each row? Where does the CSRF token value come from in your AJAX request?

Comment: @CBroe: The table is not inside a form. The CSRF token value comes from the header file included in the view.

Comment: And when/how does the CSRF token get created? Is it a different one for each request, or is it “static”?

Comment: @CBroe: Does that matter? Because there is only one POST request.

Comment: It could matter, if the creation of a new token was triggered several times - because then your request might be using a “previous” one, and therefor comparison would fail.

Comment: @CBroe: I have changed the order of data in POST(first the token then the array) and that error is gone. But now another error "Array to string conversion". I am using CI version 2.1.3

Comment: Can you please add the PHP code for insert data i think you are passing the array into the database field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed. Some elements(starting from array(83)) of the array that is being passed to the controller by the AJAX POST was getting popped, which lead to a database error. I don't know the exact reason yet but after some research I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462840/array-being-chopped-off-over-ajax-post-ajax-posting-limit). So instead of inserting all values in a single INSERT query I have inserted one employee's one month's shift in one insert query, to be safe.

Modified the javascript to this

```js
$('#insert_shift').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var empty_td = $('.td_shift[data-type=""]').size();

  if (empty_td == 0) {

    var num_of_days = parseInt($('.th_day').last().text());
    var num_of_users = parseInt($('.user_shift_row').size());
    var insert_helper = 0;
    var post_finish_helper = 0;

    var date = $('#atdnc_date').val() + '-';
    var arr = [];
    var new_arr = [];

    function insert_shift_per_user() {

        $('.td_shift[data-inserted="0"]').each(function() {

          insert_helper++;

          var data_type = $(this).attr('data-type');
          var shift_atdnc_id = $(this).attr('data-typeid');
          var user_id = $(this).attr('data-user');
          var new_date = date + $(this).attr('data-day');

          if (data_type == 'shift') {
            var shift_strt_time = $(this).attr('data-start');
            var shift_end_time = $(this).attr('data-end'); // Change new_arr to old
            var attn_status = 0;
            var shift = shift_atdnc_id;
          } else if (data_type == 'attendance') {
            var shift_strt_time = "00:00:00";
            var shift_end_time = "00:00:00";
            var attn_status = shift_atdnc_id;
            var shift = 0;
          }

          new_arr = {
            'user_id': user_id,
            'date': new_date,
            'shift': shift,
            'attn_status': attn_status,
            'shift_strt_time': shift_strt_time,
            'shift_end_time': shift_end_time
          };

          arr.push(new_arr);

          if (insert_helper == num_of_days) {

            $.post(base_url + 'test_shift/insert_shift', {

                csrf_test_name: csrf_token,
                a: arr
              },
              function(data) {

                if (data == 1) {

                  arr = []; // clearing the array
                  new_arr = []; // clearing the new_array
                  insert_helper = 0;

                  $('.td_shift[data-user="' + user_id + '"]').attr('data-inserted', 1);

                  post_finish_helper++;

                  if (post_finish_helper == num_of_users) {
                    document.location.href = base_url + 'test_shift';
                  } else {
                    insert_shift_per_user();
                  }
                } else {
                  alert("Error");
                }

              }
            );



          } //if insert_helper == num_of_days ends

        });

      } // FUNCTION insert_shift_per_user

    insert_shift_per_user();


    //var aa = jQuery.parseJSON(arr);
    //console.log(arr);

  } else {
    alert("Please fill all the shifts");
  }



}); //insert_shift ends here
```